# How to avoid jshint saying that a const is undefined when it is referred to in a function before where it is declared?

Tags: javascript, jshint

Is there any way of rewriting the below to avoid jshint saying that `'intervalID' is not defined`, and keeping `intervalID` and `doSomething` a `const`?

```
const doSomething = () => {
    // do stuff

    if (isFinished()) {
         clearInterval(intervalID); // <--jshint complains that intervalID is not defined
    }
}

const intervalID = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
```

Comment: simple. put either `let` or `var` instead of `const`, jshint is correct in what it is saying. But to be fair, if it is working, why do you care?

Comment: I know I can use `let` or `var`, that's what I'm trying to avoid if at all possible. If it's not possible, so be it.

Comment: then just define your `const` before your function.

Comment: If I do that, jshint then complains that `'doSomething' is not defined`.

Comment: then do something like this: `const intervalID; const doSomething = () => {//your code} intervalID = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);`

Comment: A `const` needs to be initialized when it is declared, and its value can't be changed after.

Comment: To be honest, there isn't a clean way to do it, a `const` should be declared and then unchanged. I would advise you use `let` or `var` but you seem adamant that you don't want to do that, so, not much else to advise.

Comment: Why not make the function a `let`?

`let` binds to the closest function better than all the other methods and would solve your issue, wouldnt it?

Comment: Have you considered using eslint instead of jshint?

Comment: @FelixKling - eslint behaves as desired, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible in the desired way. but you could use jshint inline flags like

```
/* globals intervalID: true */
```

Comment: `/* globals intervalID: false */` results in jshint saying `Redefinition of 'intervalID'`. `/* globals intervalID: true */ ` on the other hand doesn't and avoids the original warning.

Comment: It's still not ideal though, as `intervalID` isn't really a global and jshint won't pick up errors if the above code is in its own block, and I then refer to `intervalID` outside that block.

Comment: you could also wrap it in a jshint ignore block (just the one line..); I don't see a possibility to achieve this in a cleaner way. you should not restructure your code to fit the hinter though!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just declare your variable first?

```
const intervalID;
const doSomething = () => {
// do stuff

    if (isFinished()) {
         clearInterval(intervalID); // <--jshint complains that intervalID is not defined
    }
}

intervalID = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
```

Comment: No, a `const` needs to be initialized when it is declared, and it's value can't be changed after.

Comment: What if you add this to the top of your file? Although it would not pick up any actual errors you may have: 
`/* jshint undef: false */`